# android studio can't write hebrew to pdf (basefont can't read the ttf)

Tags: android, file, pdf, exception, hebrew

I wrote a function to insert details in Hebrew into a pdf file.

```
public static String font="/src/main/res/font/arialuni.ttf";
BaseFont unicode = BaseFont.createFont(font,BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    String path= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
    File file = new File(path,startDate+"to"+endDate+".pdf");
    Document doc=new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(doc,new FileOutputStream(file));
    doc.open();

    doc.add(new Chunk(" "));
    PdfPTable pdfPTable=new PdfPTable(2);
    pdfPTable.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);

    Font selectedFont=new Font(unicode,12);
    PdfPCell pdfPCell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase("משה",selectedFont));
    PdfPCell pdfPCell2=new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Machines"));

    pdfPTable.addCell(pdfPCell);
    pdfPTable.addCell(pdfPCell2);

    doc.add(pdfPTable);

    doc.close();
    Toast.makeText(this,"PDF Created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

No matter what i tried to do, i'm getting this error:
java.io.IOException: /src/main/res/font/arialuni.ttf not found as file or resource.

As u can see in the image below, i have the ttf file in every folder.
https://i.im.ge/2021/10/08/TnDOB9.png

Comment: You seem to be using iText. iText knows nothing about Android resources or assets. Your value for `font` does not seem to reflect a location that iText will be able to use.

Comment: ok, So what should i need to change to read a ttf file for my pdf?

Comment: Try `assets/Fonts/arialuni.ttf` for `font`, based on some results that I am seeing elsewhere in Stack Overflow.

Comment: It is working!!!! thankssss!!!!